# How to make a array of object size (10,2) to 2d array of float (10,2) in Python

Tags: python, arrays, concatenation

I have an array of object X_init: array of object (10,2) and I want to convert it to an 2d Array of int (10,2).

```
X_init = 11,4
         11,6
         21,4
         ...
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, in terms of what is that object and what you already have. It seems using `np.array()` or `np.reshape` appropriately might help you achieve your goal, check the documentation.